ASP.NET Core 8 Web API: response including IFormFile
I want to post a file to a web server that will validate and return another file after validation.
This is from the server:
[HttpPost("UploadFile")]
[Route("test")]
public FileInformation CreateGame([FromForm] FileInformation fileInformation)
{
    FileInformation f = new FileInformation();
    f.Name = fileInformation.Name;
    f.Description = fileInformation.Description;
    f.File = fileInformation.File; // the console cannot convert this

    //System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("wwwroot\\", fileInformation.File);
    try
    {
        using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream("wwwroot\\" + fileInformation.Name, FileMode.Create))
        {
            fileInformation.File.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
    }
    catch { }

    return fileInformation;
}

public class FileInformation
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}

This part is from the console application
string filePath = @"TextFile1.txt";

using var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
using var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath));

fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");

form.Add(fileContent, "File", Path.GetFileName(filePath));

form.Add(new StringContent("TextFile1.txt"), "Name");
form.Add(new StringContent("TextFile1.txt"), "Description");

var httpClient = new HttpClient()
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7009")
};

var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"/api/UploadScore/test", form);

//response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

FileInformation f = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileInformation>(responseContent);

If I populate the File property in fileInformation, the code crashes upon conversion. I can't figure this out.
I have tried to convert using ReadAsArray.
I want to be able to retrieve a file from the server.

"it crashes upon conversion" - How does it "crash"?  If the operation is producing an exception, catch and observe that exception to see the error.  As an aside... Why does the CreateGame method have an errant return null; at the end?  The compiler is surely warning you about unreachable code, it's best not to ignore compiler warnings.

yes it is warning about  unreachable code.

the client it receives the response but i cant convert it to fileinformation object,
{"name":"TextFile1.txt","description":"TextFile1.txt","file":{"contentType":"multipart/form-data","contentDisposition":"form-data; name=File; filename=TextFile1.txt; filename*=utf-8''TextFile1.txt","headers":{"Content-Type":["multipart/form-data"],"Content-Disposition":["form-data; name=File; filename=TextFile1.txt; filename*=utf-8''TextFile1.txt"]},"length":14,"name":"File","fileName":"TextFile1.txt"}}
this is the response it seems right to me except that there is no data?? and that makes me confused

After giving it a few more tries i managed to make it work by reading the saved file to byte[]
and added a new response class with byte[] instead of IFormFile
